# Emails stopped appearing in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I have Gmail configured to accept messages from my HostGator mail server. I also have Mac Mail configured to accept messages. They use IMAP.

For some reason, Gmail just does not get my messages, whereas Mac Mail does. Gmail only has messages saved in it from two months ago.

How could I fix this?

Comment: Verify your account is able to connect to the account in Account Settings.

Answer (score 1):

Your email provider may have made a change to the connection methods they support:
encrypted vs. unencrypted; encryption types; password transmission method etc.

So you might want to check the server settings in gmail vs. Mac Mail to see if you spot any differences, and additionally you may want to check out the settings recommended by your email provider.